# Using regex to automatically superscript ordinal suffixes

Tags: php, regex

I've tried to do this but I just suck at regular expressions. What I need is to have a regular expression that will replace 1st, 3rd and 9th with 1<sup>st</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and  9<sup>th</sup> by adding `<sup>` and `</sup>` around any 'rd' 'th' and 'st' that is preceded by a number and not followed by a letter or a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial, so I shall just give you the components you need.

`(?<=\d)` checks for the presence of a number immediately before the current position.

`(A|B|C)` checks for any of the regexes A, B or C in the current position.

And that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$string = "bla 1st bla 2nd bla 3rd bla 5th 9thSomethingNotToBeReplaced ";
echo preg_replace('/(\d)+(st|nd|rd|th)([^\w\d]|$)/', '$1<sup>$2</sup>$3', $string);
```

Comment: Kind of inefficient and bulky. If you want to ensure there is no word character afterward, you could just use `\b`, and the `\d` could be made a lookbehind to avoid an unnecessary capture group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you also want to handle '2nd':

```
$string = '1st, 2nd, 3rd and 9th';
echo preg_replace_callback('/1st|2nd|3rd|[4-9]th/', function($m){
    return $m[0]{0} . '<sup>' . substr($m[0], 1) . '</sup>';
  }, $string);

// 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and 9<sup>th</sup>
```

Comment: @Kolink I believe the OP only wants this for 1-digit numbers, since all the examples he gave were.